# Finding a quadratic equation from roots (Vieta's formula)

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Given $x_1 = 1-\sqrt 3$ and $x_2=1+\sqrt 3$, What is the quadratic equation?

By Vieta's formula:
$-\frac{b}{a} = 1-\sqrt 3 + 1+\sqrt 3 = 2$. Hence, $-b = 2a$
$-\frac{c}{a} = (1-\sqrt 3)(1+\sqrt 3) = -2$. Hence, $c = -2a$

I am missing the third equation needed for $a,b,c$ parameters.

Comment: I guess you mean "quadratic" (= second degree) as opposed "quartic" (= fourth degree). To give you a hint: Can you think of a way to relate the solutions of
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ with the solutions of
$$x^2+\frac bax+\frac ca=0?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, ever, I'm trying to find the quadratic equation, **given** the roots, I use the formula:
$$x^2-(\textrm{sum of roots})x+(\textrm{product of roots})=0$$ (try and prove this yourself!).

Alternatively, if the worst comes to the worst, and you forget this, then just expand $[x-(1-\sqrt{3})][x-(1+\sqrt{3})]=0.$

More generally, if we've got roots $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$ to an $n$th-order polynomial, to find said polynomial, just expand $$(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

So, the equation becomes $$at^2-2at-2a=0$$

If $a=0,$ it becomes an identity to be satisfied all finite values of $t$

else $a\ne0$, where we can cancel $a$ safely